# It's ok to use HEX as BCD function?

Tags: function, hex, bcd

I'm wondering if it's ok to use HEX as BCD function? and for decoding we can take each character and decode it  as decimal or byte..

Answer (score 0):

Hex and BCD are to different things. One is numbers base 16 and the other base ten. What may confuse is you can see ether one with hexa representation of memory.
Here is an example of memory representation:

```
004044FC : 33 31 1E 00 - 33 31 1E 00 - 32 38 1B 00 - 33 31 1E 00
0040450C : 33 30 1D 00 - 33 31 1E 00 - 33 30 1D 00 - 33 31 1E 00
0040451C : 33 31 1E 00 - 33 30 1D 00 - 48 65 6C 6C - 6F 20 54 68
0040452C : 69 73 20 69 - 73 20 74 68 - 65 20 74 65 - 73 74 20 6F
```